# Can sync be done using denormalized tables locally using ColdFusion ActionScript ORM Library

Tags: apache-flex, orm, coldfusion, air

We are working on a flex air sync application using the ColdFusion ActionScript ORM Library. Since we have just started with this, I had a basic question. The remote database is a huge one with lot of tables and relation ships and we are implementing a small portion of the functionality for the sync application. Hence we are planning to use some de-normalized tables for the local database (sqlite). 
I just wanted to know whether sync would work when we have de-normalized tables locally i.e the local DB and the remote DB are not exactly similar. We are using ColdFusion 9.0.1 ActionScript ORM Library.
Also, if this can be done then where have to handle the differences ? ( I suppose on the server cold fusion side)

Thanks,

Comment: "I just wanted to know whether sync would work when we have de-normalized tables locally" I voted to close, as it appears you are asking if the application you are about to write will work.

Comment: My question is whether the concept will work i.e maintaining de-normalized tables will work or we will have to have tables in the local SQLite DB that are same as remote database ?

Comment: Sure, it'll work.  Someone will have to write the code to make it work.  It's not a whole lot different than importing an excel sheet into multiple tables.  Why does this even need to be asked?